# Android title buttons

Tags: android, android-widget, title

I am trying to reproduce the account chooser widget that the GMail app has on top right.
I know already how to put things in the title but i have several problems:

- I've tried putting a normal button in the title but it doesn't fit
- It looks like the size of the title is bigger than what it is, for example if I put a normal button there, there is no way of making it the proper height, in fact goes below the app like if half of the title space was hidden below
- I thought it might be a clickable label with a rectangular shape, but I tried it and no way to make it work.

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the layout using the hierarchy viewer it seems like it really is just a `Button` inside a `LinearLayout`. The only interesting part is that the `LinearLayout`'s `layout_height` is set to `MATCH_PARENT` (which is just the newer version of `FILL_PARENT`) where its parent the `RelativeLayout` has a hardcoded `layout_height` of `54`.
[image]

I'm not sure if this is of help for you but maybe it can point you in the right direction.

Comment: This might make sense now, btw, how did u get this info? Extracted the gmail apk and used a program?

Comment: @Arkaitz Jimenez: No. I've just fired up the `hierarchyviewer` which is included in your `sdk/tools` directory and fetched the layout of the Gmail app. You can do that too.

Comment: Cool I didn't know about this tool, looks like you can fetch any layout from any installed app.

Comment: @Arkaitz Jimenez: Yea the hierarchyviewer is one of the most valuable assets when it comes to UI design and especially debugging.